# saspy - establishing iomcom connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sas, saspy

I am trying to setup a connection to remote SAS server using IOMCOM. I've configured sascfg_personal.py file with iomhost iomport class_id and encoding.
Then when I import saspy and try to run this code:

```
saspy.SASsession(results="TEXT")
```

Next it asks me for username and password which I enter. After that and ***com_error: -2147352567*** is thrown. Inside it there is a SASMessage which reads:

```
<SASMessage severity="Error">Unknown username.</SASMessage>
```

This suggested me that my configuration is correct. I am also using SAS EG so I looked up declared automatic system variables. I've tried typing in values of ***_CLIENTUSERID, CLIENTUSERNAME or _METAUSER*** variables and none of them worked.
Where I can find my actual username? Or maybe this error is caused by something else?

Comment: Is this a private SAS installation or On Demand?

Comment: This is not On Demand installation.